# Jquery UI Sortable - назначить сортируемым списком динамически созданные элементы

Tags: jquery, ui, sortable

Добрый день.
Проблема такого рода.
Создаю проект, в котором есть много сортируемых списков и элементы можно создавать динамически.
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, которую пока не могу решить:
у меня во время работы динамически создаются родительские элементы и дочерние к ним, дочерние внутри родительских должны сортироваться, всё происходит без перезагрузки страницы
при загрузке все созданные списки сортируются, а динамически созданные связки родитель-дочерние не хотят даже после насильного назначения
заметил что даже спустя секунду после загрузки назначение sortable списка не работает

есть функция:

```
function _sortable(list,elements,handle_s) {
    $(list).sortable({
        handle: handle_s,
        update: function () {
            length = $(elements).length;
            var sort = length;
            var arr = {};
            arr["table_name"] = $("#table_name").val();
            setTimeout(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    var sort_id = $(elements + ":eq(" + i + ") .id_hidden").val();
                    arr[sort] = sort_id;
                    sort--;
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/php/sort.php',
                    data: arr,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response)
                    }
                });
            }, 350);
        }
    });
};
```

если я её пускаю во время выполнения скрипта

```
_sortable("#list", ".item_level1", ".handle_main");
```

всё работает

если делаю тайминг даже на секунду

```
setTimeout(function () {
    _sortable("#list", ".item_level1", ".handle_main");
}, 1000);
```

то перестаёт

Comment: Нашёл решение. Далее за скриптом была подключена другая версия jquery. После её отключения всё заработало. Как вариант можно не отключать, а использовать jquery noconflict.

Answer (score 1):

из комментария:

Нашёл решение. Далее за скриптом была подключена другая версия jquery. После её отключения всё заработало. Как вариант можно не отключать, а использовать [JQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).